# Wufoo date form javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

Hye guys,

I installed a wufoo form on one of my websites. It links to a javascript file that I have referenced from their server. The date picker is supposed to work by opening a little pop-up modal with a calendar where the user can click on a date and have the fields auto-updated. This date picker button on this site is a little calendar icon next to the date fields.

This used to work before but I just checked now and all of a sudden it's not working. I tried to fix it by copying the JS into a seperate .js file that I am referencing on my server. This still does not work.

Was wondering if anyone knows how I can fix this, or what silly syntax error I have made somewhere.

The website in question is http://www.healthassistinternational.com/free-quote.html

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I enter your website and look at the console, there are three errors:

```
- free-quote.html:157  -- Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
- free-quote.html:491  -- Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
- /menu.js:12          -- Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'hover'
```

I think you put Wufoo's javascript on a wrong place, it should be placed in the `<head/>` element. So, move `<script src="http://wufoo.com/scripts/public/dynamic.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>` to the head-element, before `Calender.something()` is called